# gcc-4.0 not found, symlink to gcc is no good

Tags: gcc

I've seen a few posts about my same error, but the solution suggested does not work for me. I'm on OS X Mavericks.

When running 'pip install psycopg2', it fails with the error:

```
...
unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

The suggested solution is to just have gcc-4.0 link to gcc.

When I cd to /usr/bin and link gcc-4.0 to gcc with the command 'sudo ln -s gcc gcc-4.0', and again run 'pip install psycopg2', it gives me this error:

```
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

where the 20 errors above include "`Unsupported architecture`" and "`unknown type name '__uint32_t`'" and a bunch of other random things. It seems it really wanted gcc-4.0 and not gcc.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X doesn't use regular GCC in its Xcode tools, which is why you are seeing these errors. With some effort you can compile a standard version of the GCC yourself, or get it from Fink, MacPorts, homebrew, etc. There are also instructions here http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2010/11/11/links-about-building-psycopg-mac-os-x/

Yes, although the instructions look dated, they are still applicable. I've been porting packages for Mac OS X since the Fink project started in 2001, and changes in the basic Linux/Unix -> Mac OS X porting process are relatively minor between 2010 and 2014 (in my perspective at least, compared to changes since 10.0 was first released on March 24, 2001).

If your objective is merely to have/use psycopg2 on your OS X machine, rather than discovering how to compile it, then you should be satisfied with a binary package installation via one of the package management systems I mentioned above, and which are also listed below under installation for Mac OS X:

http://initd.org/psycopg/install/